# Count records in different time ranges in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, timestamp

I have a pandas Dataframe consisting of 3 columns like this:

```
   no                                 id                  timestamp 
0   4  ab729f70-f3f3-4c57-94e5-e8408b2b0a80 2017-09-09 12:51:56.642810  
1   3  ab729f70-f3f3-4c57-94e5-e8408b2b0a80 2017-09-09 12:35:57.412720 
2   2  ab729f70-f3f3-4c57-94e5-e8408b2b0a80 2017-09-09 12:35:56.559890 
3   1  ab729f70-f3f3-4c57-94e5-e8408b2b0a80 2017-09-09 12:35:54.616122
```

The idea is to count records (rows in the dataset) in **last** 1 min, 5 min, 15 min, 180 min, 1 day, 10 days and 25 days based on column **timestamp**. This should be pretty straightforward but I didn't manage to solve it. For example, I used TimeGrouper option, but that gave me occurances in specified time range (let's say 1 min) but *for all records*:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='timestamp',freq='1Min')).count()
```

output:

```
                      no    id 
timestamp                            
2017-09-09 12:35:00   3      3 
2017-09-09 12:36:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:37:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:38:00   0      0
2017-09-09 12:39:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:40:00   0      0
2017-09-09 12:41:00   0      0
2017-09-09 12:42:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:43:00   0      0
2017-09-09 12:44:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:45:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:46:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:47:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:48:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:49:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:50:00   0      0 
2017-09-09 12:51:00   1      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateOffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) for previous datetime, then get boolen mask by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) and last count `True`s by `sum`:

```
now = pd.datetime.now() 
print (now)
2017-09-09 17:10:29.265217

print (now - pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=180))
2017-09-09 14:10:29.265217

a = df['timestamp'].between(now - pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=180), now).sum()
print (a)
0
```

---

```
b = df['timestamp'].between(now - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1), now).sum()
print (b)
4
```

If need custom datetime:

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2017-09-09 12:45:00')
print (date)
2017-09-09 12:45:00

c = df['timestamp'].between(date - pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=15), date).sum()
print (c)
3
```

Comment: I believe this works, thank you! BTW, I need to calculate this for each time range right? Suppose it will be fast enough...

Comment: In my opinion the best is verify it in small dataframe and then apply solution to all data. Thank you and nice weekend!